# For a field $K$ of characteristics $p>0$, when is a finite purely inseparable extension $F/K$ (with $[F:K]=p^n>1$) such that $F\cong K$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

An example that illustrates  the question is:  $F=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and $K=\mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$, for which
$F\cong K$ by Luroth's theorem.

Also, for   $p>3$, consider  $F=\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p(x,y)$, where $y^3=x^2+1$.
If  $K=\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p(x^p,y^p)$, then  we have $[F:K]=p$ and $F\cong K$.

I suspect that $F\cong K$ is not true in general, and I'm looking for  necessary and sufficient conditions for that to hold.
Any idea/reference   is welcome!

Comment: That first example has nothing to do with separability, nor with positive characteristic. We have $k(t)\cong  k(t^n)$ for any natural $n$, and any field $k$.

Comment: @Arthur. You are right! We can even replace $t^n$ by rational functions. But I see no harm in using it  as  an example.